# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':payu-non-seam-less-react:releaseRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, payment-gateway, payu

I was using the PayU payment gateway since last year in a project and it was working fine but when I'm using that project now then i getting error:-

```
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':payu-non-seam-less-react:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve in.payu:payu-crash-logger:[1.0.4,1.1.0).
     Required by:
         project :payu-non-seam-less-react > in.payu:payu-checkout-pro:1.8.9
         project :payu-non-seam-less-react > in.payu:payu-checkout-pro:1.8.9 > in.payu:payu-sdk:5.4.7
      > Failed to list versions for in.payu:payu-crash-logger.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeIntentSDK/in/payu/payu-crash-logger/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeIntentSDK/in/payu/payu-crash-logger/maven-metadata.xml'.    
               > Could not GET 'https://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeIntentSDK/in/payu/payu-crash-logger/maven-metadata.xml'. Received 
status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I resolve this problem
first i **uninstall payu-non-seam-less-react** (means old version)

then install the latest version.

but then I stuck with new errors then I clear the build(./gradlew clean)

and then I added below code in `android/gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

then run this project.